# What is the difference between “Keep on” and “keep as it is”?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, phrase-usage

Does “Keep on” and “keep as it is” have same meaning? When and where we can use these?

*For example*: I have to tell my friend to keep a thing as in the same way

> I think it is better to keep as it is.

Is my usage correct?

Comment: Could you provide a couple of example sentences which use these phrases?

Comment: To echo Steve's thoughts, this question could sure use some improvements. For starters, the phrase _keep on_ has at least [**five** possible meanings](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/keep+on) – which ones don't you understand and are therefore asking about? As for where can you use them, there are a host of possibilities, such as "They had very fancy china plates they would **keep on** the hutch." For more information and ideas about asking good questions, look [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Keep on*** is a phrasal verb taking a gerund clause as its complement; it means “continue [a course of action]”. It is an intensive version of plain *keep* in this sense.

> Bob kept on interrupting me, so I couldn't finish. ... *Bob continued to interrupt me*
> Laura kept on writing until the chapter was done. ... *Laura continued to write*

It often has the sense of “persevere”, as in the 60s-70s catchphrase

> Keep on keeping on.  ... *Don't give up the struggle to achieve/survive*

***Keep ... as it is*** is not a fixed phrase but the transitive verb *keep*, meaning “maintain [something] [in a specified condition]”  combined with the phrase *as it is* serving as the second complement with the meaning “in its present condition”.

> Ryan wanted to change the second sentence, but we decided to keep it as it was.
> Let's keep the schedule as it is for now. We can update it when we know more.

Answer (score 1):

You asked about:

> *I think it is better to keep as it is*.

I would add one word:

> I think it is better to keep **it** as it is.

Alternatively, you can say:

> I think it is better to keep **things as they are**.

The word *things* can be used if you are talking about a situation or arrangement (even if you are only talking about one "thing"):

> **Cindy**: Right now, we meet for lunch every other Tuesday. Do you want to move that to Thursday?
>   **Mindy**: I think it would be better to keep things as they are.

As for *keep on*, that could be used in a similar context, but I would be less vague when using *keep on*, avoiding words like "things" and "it":

> **Sandy**: Right now, we meet for lunch every other Tuesday. Do you want to move that to Thursday?
>   **Mandy**: I think it would be better to keep on meeting on Tuesdays.