# Exact difference between "keep doing" and "keep on doing"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

I often come across sentences like these

> He kept **on** chasing the thief even it's deep into the night.
>   Shall we keep practicing in the next few days?

But as far as I'm concerned, both of the following sounds fairly OK.

> He kept chasing the thief ...
>   Shall we keep **on** practicing ...?

I can barely remember that they have a monir difference in meaning but I Googled (and searched ELL.SE) around and found only usage differences. Can anyone tell the exact difference **in meaning**?

Comment: The answers to this question might be helpful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/27467/ and this one as well: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/11768/

Comment: @ColleenV Reading both without solving my question lead me to post this one.

Answer (score 3):

When you say *keep doing X*, it means twothings: A) you expect X to be finished soon or at a definite time, and B) you were already doing X

> Keep looking at this report.

When you say *keep on doing X*, it means two things: A) you're talking about making X part of a routine or background activity, and B) you were already doing it.

> Keep on looking at these reports everyday.

It can also mean to progress further with a path or course.  In these cases you can omit the *-ing* word if it will be understood from context.

> Keep on walking down the path until you get to the house.  ("Keep on down the path until you get to the house" also works.)
>
> Keep on driving until you are past 5th street.  ("Keep on until you are past 5th street" also works.)

Answer (score 1):

To the idea of "persistence" that comes from "keep" + {verb}ing, the word **on** adds a vague sense of forward motion (*onward* in space|time) and so it serves to make the abstract idea of "persistence" more concrete, which makes the statement more emphatic.